# ES6 filter in a filter is this possible?

Tags: javascript

I have an Array that looks like this:

[image]

I need the id where `slug === 'slug'`

```
let activeFaq = this.faq.filter(obj => obj.items.filter(item => item.slug === 'slug'));
console.log(activeFaq.id);
```

This gives me an undefined. I should get 2729

Comment: `filter` returns an array

Comment: Are the slugs unique in the whole `faq` array? If not, what do you expect to happen if there are duplicates?

Comment: @FelixKling yes they are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could go about this. If you can use [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), then one solution would be to flatten all items into a single array and then use `.find`:

```
const item = this.faq.flatMap(obj => obj.items).find(item => item.slug === 'slug')
```

However, flattening seems a bit unnecessary. An approach that avoid unnecessary computations would be a helper function with a boring loop:

```
function findItem(faqs, callback) {
  for (const faq of faqs) {
    const item = faq.find(callback);
    if (item) {
      return item;
    }
  }
}


const activeFaq = findItem(this.faq, item => item.slug === 'slug');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var activeFaq = this.faq.filter(obj => obj.items.some(item => item.slug === 'slug'))[0];
console.log(activeFaq.items[0].id); //2729
```

Comment: This is assuming there will only be 1 itemn there can be x amount of objects in items array

Comment: Loop over the activeFaq.items array for all the matching ids , where the item.slug condition satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

```
let activeFaq = this.faq.reduce( ( obj ) => {
  const foundItem = obj.items.find( ( item ) => {
     return item.slug === 'slug'
  } )

  if( foundItem ) {
    acc = foundItem
  }

  return acc

}, null )

console.log(activeFaq.id);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.